# InvalidRequestError when mixing dataclass and AssociationProxy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use an AssociationProxy to get an attribute of a parent class, when I add the AssociationProxy to the child class it behaves normally, but when I add an AssociationProxy to the Parent class (to another class) I get the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Parent(parents)], expression 'Child' failed to locate a name ('Child'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class '__main__.Parent'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.`

An example that reproduces the error. When the specified line is uncommented, the error is thrown.

```
import json
import dataclasses
from typing import List

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped, MappedAsDataclass, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy, AssociationProxy

class Base(DeclarativeBase): pass

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Gender(Base):
     __tablename__ = "genders"

     id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
     gender: Mapped[str]

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    gender_id = mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey("genders.id"))
    gender_ = relationship("Gender")
    children: Mapped[List["Child"]] = relationship("Child")
    # when the following line is uncommented, an InvalidRequestError is thrown
    # gender: AssociationProxy[str] = association_proxy("gender_", "gender")

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "children"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey("parents.id"))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
    parent_name: AssociationProxy[str] = association_proxy("parent", "name")

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

class EnhancedJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if dataclasses.is_dataclass(o):
                return dataclasses.asdict(o)
            return super().default(o)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    with Session() as session:
        gender = Gender(gender="M")
        session.add(gender)
        parent = Parent(name="John", gender_=gender, children=[Child(), Child()])
        session.add(parent)
        session.commit()
    
    with Session() as session:
        parent = session.query(Parent).first()
        print(json.dumps(parent, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder, indent=2))
```